# TouchID with KeyChain - Enter Passcode screen appears malformed (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, keychain, touch-id

I am having a hard time with this one: 
Our app uses TouchID to retrieve secrets from the KeyChain that are used to authenticate to a WebApp in a WKWebView.  All is fine when the user successfully authenticates with TouchID.  
The problem arises when the user fails TouchID and then taps on "Enter Passcode" to authenticate via device passcode instead.  I noticed that the screen that gets presented is plain white, and the passcode text-box does not show a value for the last character entered until it is masked, creating a strange user experience.  This seems like a bug to me, unless I am somehow missing a configuration requirement.

```
    // global arguments for the touchId keychain queries
    let kSecClassValue = NSString(format: kSecClass)
    let kSecAttrAccountValue = NSString(format: kSecAttrAccount)
    let kSecValueDataValue = NSString(format: kSecValueData)
    let kSecClassGenericPasswordValue = NSString(format: kSecClassGenericPassword)
    let kSecAttrServiceValue = NSString(format: kSecAttrService)
    let kSecMatchLimitValue = NSString(format: kSecMatchLimit)
    let kSecReturnDataValue = NSString(format: kSecReturnData)
    let kSecMatchLimitOneValue = NSString(format: kSecMatchLimitOne)
    let kSecAttrAccessControlValue = NSString(format: kSecAttrAccessControl)
    let kSecUseOperationPromptValue = NSString(format: kSecUseOperationPrompt)

    // set access control
    let accessControl = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
        kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly, .UserPresence, nil)
    // Instantiate a new default keychain query
    // Tell the query to return a result
    // Limit our results to one item
    var keychainQuery: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPasswordValue, service, userAccount, kCFBooleanTrue, kSecMatchLimitOneValue, "Place your finger to authenticate.", accessControl.takeUnretainedValue()], forKeys: [kSecClassValue, kSecAttrServiceValue, kSecAttrAccountValue, kSecReturnDataValue, kSecMatchLimitValue, kSecUseOperationPromptValue, kSecAttrAccessControlValue])

    var dataTypeRef :Unmanaged<AnyObject>?

    // Search for the keychain item
    touchIdStatusCode = SecItemCopyMatching(keychainQuery, &dataTypeRef)
```

Here is the generated keychainQuery dictionary:

```
{
    "accc" = "<SecAccessControlRef: 0x170621140>";
    "acct" = “MY_ACCOUNT”;
    "class" = genp;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitOne";
    "r_Data" = 1;
    "svce" = “MY_SERVICE”;
    "u_OpPrompt" = "Place your finger to authenticate.";
}
```

This behavior exists on the latest iOS version (8.4).  Here is the screen  I was referring to:
[image: Enter Passcode for KeyChain TouchID]

My question is: Am I somehow causing the screen to be broken by the way I am invoking TouchID?  Or is this perfectly normal for this scenario?

Thanks, and sorry for the lengthy post!

Comment: Hey Hi, i need small help on Showing pass code screen when Touch ID fails, please help on this

Comment: Would it make sense to post your question?  Maybe others can weigh in as well.

Comment: if you don't mind, please confirm it, is it possible or not? if possible please assist me.

Comment: I have exactly same problem on iPhone. It's even worse on iPad. Keyboard is not visible, but it's there and you can touch white space and characters appear in passcode box. Did you try raise a bug on radar?

Comment: Not yet, I was waiting for somebody else to indicate that they ran into the same issue.  I think I will do that now.

Comment: Filed: rdar://22310753

Comment: I got confirmation today that this is a bug.  Apple stated that the bug report I filed is a duplicate.  I guess this means that it will be fixed at some point.  I have not tested this in iOS 9 yet, but will do so shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue described is a bug that was confirmed by Apple engineers.  It still exists as of iOS 9.0.2.